# How to create inline button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I hope to create a layout where a button and text are aligned in the same row. I think the ideal implementation should be similar to the code below. (But SwiftUI currently does not actually support this layout.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You can in")+Button("Next Page", action: {})+Text("see more")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method maintains the inline layout while also implementing the button functionality. It utilizes the `Link` support of the `Text` element, using a `Link` to trigger a specific action, and intercepts this `Link` in the view to trigger a custom closure.

```
struct ContentViewV1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            let buttonLink = try! AttributedString(markdown: "[Next Page](inApp://nextPage)")
            
            Text("You can in ")+Text(buttonLink)+Text(" see more")
        }
        .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
            if url.absoluteString == "inApp://nextPage" {
                print("Next Page Button Tapped")
                return .handled
            } else {
                return .systemAction
            }
          
         })
    }
}
```